# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of Entity.id

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I've the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3454567L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int empId;

    @Column
    private String username;

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

And the following EJB:

```
public class UserDAO implements UserDAOInterface{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MainPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void persist(Employee sdf) {
        try {
            em.persist(sdf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

When persist is called, an exception with the following root cause is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.mine.projs.library.entity.Employee.empId
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 100 more
```

Here's the full log from GlassFish 4.1:

```
Info:   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: MainPersistenceUnit
    ...]
Info:   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
Info:   HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Info:   HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Info:   HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Info:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
Info:   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Info:   HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Info:   Hibernate: drop table if exists Employee
Info:   Hibernate: create table Employee (empId integer not null auto_increment, username varchar(255), primary key (empId)) ENGINE=InnoDB
Info:   HHH000230: Schema export complete
Info:   Portable JNDI names for EJB UserService: [java:global/Library/UserService, java:global/Library/UserService!com.mine.projs.library.service.interfaces.UserServiceInterface]
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Info:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context '/libr'
Info:   Running on PrimeFaces 5.1
Info:   Loading application [Library] at [/libr]
Info:   Library was successfully deployed in 3,429 milliseconds.
Info:   inside getAna
Info:   inside Create User
Severe:   exception caught
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.mine.projs.library.entity.Employee.empId
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
    at com.mine.projs.library.dao.UserDAO.persist(UserDAO.java:20)
    at com.mine.projs.library.service.UserService.createUSer(UserService.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor151.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy321.createUSer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:414)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at com.mine.projs.library.service.UserServiceInterface$243194531$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.createUSer(Unknown Source)
    at com.mine.projs.library.view.UserBean.getAna(UserBean.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.getValue(UICommand.java:218)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.ButtonRenderer.encodeBegin(ButtonRenderer.java:119)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.mine.projs.library.entity.Employee.empId
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 100 more
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: On a side note, the Employee class does not have a Table annotation but that shouldn't be the root cause.  Are there any other jpa entities that include the Employee class mapping?

Comment: This line in the provided StackTrace : `org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter` basically implies some mapping problems between associations among entities. Thus, the root cause basically is only Hibernate/JPA hereby the rest of those question tags are just fake tags. Moreover, those associations are invisible according to the current status of the question. You had better separate the exact problem domain removing the whole JSF noise to attract Hibernate/JPA experts and to get better help sooner.

Comment: You may try by changing GenerationType.AUTO to GenerationType.IDENTITY

Comment: (at)Andy There is no other entities... (at)Tiny Thanks to BalusC, he already cleaned up my mess. (at)Prakash.. I already tried all types with no difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue.  This bug seems to have started with HB 4.3.6 and has survived, I am trying 4.3.10; with the same results.

It seems to me that the way entities' fields are accessed changed in HB 4.3.6+, probably related with the class loader.  Prior to HB 4.3.6, embedding the DB driver jar file in the ear file works fine (very easy and clean for deployment).  After 4.3.6, it doesn't work (with a class not found exception), now the driver jar file has to be put in the lib folder of Glassfish.

Juan

Comment: Just found the solution.  Look at https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9446.  Add  hibernate.classloading.use_current_tccl_as_parent=false in the hibernate.properties file or the persistence.xml file.

Comment: @ jfarjona OMG you're THE MAN! I spent 10 hours searching for a solution for this. Can you explain what it does?

Answer (score 1):

That come from a classloader issue, when hibernate load initial class on deployment, a dummy classLoader is created to build catalogue. When your are at runtime, the class in the catalogue doesn't have the same class loader and the method of sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj failed.

```
protected void ensureObj(Object obj)
{
    if(!field.getDeclaringClass().isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()))
    {
        throwSetIllegalArgumentException(obj);
    }
}
```

This method is called from DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(Object) line: 57

I solve the problem in glassfish 4.1 and hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar by creating a custom jpa provider whose attach the right class loader.

```
package org.hibernate.jpa;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo;

import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;

/**
 * Lazy HibernatePersistenceProvider whose take Thread class loader as source
 * and not the dummy one
 * 
 * @author Alexandre Heroux
 *
 */
public class LazyHibernatePersistenceProvider extends HibernatePersistenceProvider {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public EntityManagerFactory createContainerEntityManagerFactory(final PersistenceUnitInfo info,
            final Map properties) {
        return (EntityManagerFactory) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
                new Class[] { EntityManagerFactory.class }, new InvocationHandler() {
                    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;

                    @Override
                    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                        return method.invoke(getEntityManagerFactory(info, properties), args);
                    }

                    /**
                     * Create the EntityManagerFactory when is not exists
                     * 
                     * @param info
                     * @param properties
                     * @return
                     */
                    protected EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo info, Map properties) {
                        if (entityManagerFactory == null) {
                            synchronized (this) {
                                if (entityManagerFactory == null) {
                                    entityManagerFactory = LazyHibernatePersistenceProvider.this
                                            .createParentContainerEntityManagerFactory(info, properties);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return entityManagerFactory;
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Call parent method
     * 
     * @param info
     * @param properties
     * @return
     */
    protected EntityManagerFactory createParentContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo info, Map properties) {
        return super.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(info, properties);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with Hibernate.

> The following exception is thrown when trying to persist a new "Product" entity (see test case) by Hibernate 4.3.6.FINAL. However, it works perfectly fine if I change the maven dependency to 4.3.5.FINAL without touching any other piece of code.

From the [Hibernate issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9434)

So I suggest changing Hibernate's version to 4.3.5. I had the same problem and that fixed it.

Answer (score -3):

Your class should have the fields mapped to the table column using annotation like

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3454567L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @cloumn(name="emp_id")
    private int empId;

    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String username;

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it with no luck. The table gets created in the database no problems. The exception occurs when persisting.