# Camel Jpa Hibernate Property access exception After bundle restart in Karaf Container

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, apache-camel, jbossfuse

Fairly new to the JPA and I have a camel route using it so I am having some trouble understanding exactly what my problem is and how to fix it.  After a bunch more testing I came to realize that this error seems to only occur after restarting my bundle in my karaf container.  If I load the container for the first time and just install it everything seems to run fine.  I added my feature file information

```
Version information:
JBoss 6.2.1
Camel Version: 2.15.1.redhat-621084
Hibernate Version: 4.2.20.Final-redhat-1


from(exceptionInputQueue).routeId("PackageExceptionRoute")
        .unmarshal(exceptionDataFormat).id("UnmarshalException")
        .convertBodyTo(ExceptionEntity.class).id("ExceptionModelToEntity")
        .to("jpa:" + ExceptionEntity.class.getName()).id("PersistExceptionEntity");

@Entity
@Table(name = "Exception")
public class ExceptionEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PackageTrackingNumber", updatable = false, nullable = false, length = 18)
    private String packageTrackingNumber;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "ExceptionTimestamp")
    private Date exceptionTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "InformationSourceCode", length = 2)
    private String informationSourceCode;

    @Column(name = "ExceptionReasonCode", length = 2)
    private String exceptionReasonCode;

    @Column(name = "ExceptionResolutionCode", length = 2)
    private String exceptionResolutionCode;

    @Column(name = "ExceptionStatusCode", length = 2)
    private String exceptionStatusCode;

    @Column(name = "ExceptionCountryCode", length = 2)
    private String exceptionCountryCode;

    @Column(name = "ExceptionLocationNumber", length = 5)
    private String exceptionLocationNumber;

    //... hashcode, equals, toString, and getters/setters excluded
}
```

Camel Context

```
<camelContext id="PackageExceptionRouteContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    streamCache="true">
    <routeBuilder ref="PackageExceptionRoute" />
</camelContext>

<bean id="PackageExceptionRoute" class="com.ups.ops.cipe.internal.route.PackageExceptionRoute">
    <property name="exceptionInputQueue" value="ibmmq:queue:myQueueName" />
    <property name="exceptionDataFormat" ref="GsonDataFormat" />
</bean>

<bean id="GsonDataFormat" class="org.apache.camel.component.gson.GsonDataFormat">
    <property name="unmarshalType"
        value="com.ups.ops.cipe.internal.eud.model.EudExceptionModel" />
    <property name="dateFormatPattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS' 'X" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpa" class="org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaComponent">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PackageException" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    <property name="showSql" value="false" />
    <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource"> 
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />  
    <property name="url" value="myDBURL" />
    <property name="username"  value="myUser" />       
    <property name="password"  value="myPass" />        
</bean> 

<bean id="transactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="ibmmq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent"
    destroy-method="doStop">
    <property name="transacted" value="false" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="acceptMessagesWhileStopping" value="true" />
    <property name="acknowledgementModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE" />
    <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER" />
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory"
            destroy-method="destroy">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
                    <property name="transportType" value="1" />
                    <property name="channel" value="myChannel" />
                    <property name="hostName" value="myHostname" />
                    <property name="port" value="myPort" />
                    <property name="queueManager" value="myQueueManager" />
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="PackageException" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.ups.ops.cipe.external.exception.entity.ExceptionEntity</class>
    <properties>            
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Feature File

```
<feature name="myFeature-all" version="${project.version}">
    <feature>camel-gson</feature>
    <feature>camel-quartz</feature>
    <feature>camel-jpa</feature>
    <feature>camel-jgroups</feature>
    <feature>hibernate</feature>
    <bundle>mvn:com.fun.my.project/PackageExceptionBundle/${project.version}</bundle>
</feature>
```

Stack Trace

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.ups.ops.cipe.external.exception.entity.ExceptionEntity.packageTrackingNumber
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)[277:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.2.20.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)[277:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.2.20.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316)[277:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.2.20.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:898)[277:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.2.20.Final-redhat-1]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)[:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)[261:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-orm:3.2.12.RELEASE_2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.merge(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaProducer$1.save(JpaProducer.java:102)[264:org.apache.camel.camel-jpa:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaProducer$1.doInTransaction(JpaProducer.java:78)[264:org.apache.camel.camel-jpa:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)[140:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-tx:3.2.12.RELEASE_2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaProducer.process(JpaProducer.java:61)[264:org.apache.camel.camel-jpa:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[146:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:167)[146:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:304)[146:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:162)[146:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[146:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)[146:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[146:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[146:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[146:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[146:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)[146:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)[146:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:103)[150:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.15.1.redhat-621084]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:562)[141:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.12.RELEASE_2]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:500)[141:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.12.RELEASE_2]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468)[141:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.12.RELEASE_2]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)[141:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.12.RELEASE_2]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)[141:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.12.RELEASE_2]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1101)[141:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.12.RELEASE_2]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1093)[141:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.12.RELEASE_2]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:990)[141:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.12.RELEASE_2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.ups.ops.cipe.external.exception.entity.ExceptionEntity.packageTrackingNumber
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:62)[279:org.hibernate.core:4.2.20.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:344)[279:org.hibernate.core:4.2.20.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4550)[279:org.hibernate.core:4.2.20.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:158)[279:org.hibernate.core:4.2.20.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:86)[279:org.hibernate.core:4.2.20.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:833)[279:org.hibernate.core:4.2.20.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:817)[279:org.hibernate.core:4.2.20.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:821)[279:org.hibernate.core:4.2.20.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:889)[277:org.hibernate.entitymanager:4.2.20.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field com.ups.ops.cipe.external.exception.entity.ExceptionEntity.packageTrackingNumber to com.ups.ops.cipe.external.exception.entity.ExceptionEntity
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)[:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)[:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)[:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)[:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)[:1.8.0_66]
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:59)[279:org.hibernate.core:4.2.20.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: sure you have a `public` method named  `getPackageTrackingNumber()` in your POJO class?

Comment: Yes I have both getters and setters for every variable including the PackageTrackingNumber:  public String getPackageTrackingNumber() {return packageTrackingNumber;}

Comment: Maybe this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771440/javax-persistence-persistenceexception-org-hibernate-propertyaccessexception-c  _Add hibernate.classloading.use_current_tccl_as_parent=false in the hibernate.properties file or the persistence.xml file._

Comment: I tried loading the new property you mentioned into my persistence.xml file, however, I am not seeing any changes I am still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a nice large amount of fun it appears that OSGI and Hibernate weren't playing very well.  I found some JIRA tickets for enhancements to improve this.  For now I am issuing refresh commands on the hibernate related bundles in between application uninstall and reinstall.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9818

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8501

Noted: hibernate-OSGI 6 is required for this to work correctly.

Comment: Hibernate 5 now has a very good OSGi integration, see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#osgi

Comment: Awesome fantastic link.  Good to know that once I update to the 4.3 version it looks like this got taken care of.  I will have to check the Redhat patch cycle to see if the FUSE platform will bundle that fix.  Thank you for the info!

Comment: In fact is now hibernate directly that provides karaf and jboss fuse features file https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-osgi/5.1.0.Final/hibernate-osgi-5.1.0.Final-karaf.xml